# Can not built "big-data-plugin" project

Tags: plugins, ant, ivy, pentaho, kettle

The "big-data-plugin" is the plugin for Kettle, now I need to build it with the source code, so I get the source from the [1](https://github.com/pentaho/big-data-plugin), but when I build it use ant, it failed. The detail info is:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   40  |   10  |   0   |   2   ||   35  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:resolve]
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]   io problem while parsing ivy file: http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.pom: Impossible to load parent for file:/C:/Users/***/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.oozie/oozie-core/ivy-3.1.3-incubating.xml.original. Parent=org.apache.oozie#oozie-main;3.1.3-incubating
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.apache.oozie#oozie-core;3.1.3-incubating
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\***\.ivy2\local\org.apache.oozie\oozie-main\3.1.3-incubating\ivys\ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-main;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-main.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\***\.ivy2\local\org.apache.oozie\oozie-main\3.1.3-incubating\jars\oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== pentaho-ivy: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org.apache.oozie/oozie-main/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]   ==== pentaho-mvn: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/oozie/oozie-main/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-main;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-main.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/oozie/oozie-main/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== public: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-core;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-core.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== java-net-maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-core;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-core.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== cloudera: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/cdh-build/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-core;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-core.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/cdh-build/org/apache/oozie/oozie-core/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-core-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   io problem while parsing ivy file: http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.pom: Impossible to load parent for file:/C:/Users/***/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.oozie/oozie-client/ivy-3.1.3-incubating.xml.original. Parent=org.apache.oozie#oozie-main;3.1.3-incubating
[ivy:resolve]           module not found: org.apache.oozie#oozie-client;3.1.3-incubating
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\***\.ivy2\local\org.apache.oozie\oozie-main\3.1.3-incubating\ivys\ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-main;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-main.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\***\.ivy2\local\org.apache.oozie\oozie-main\3.1.3-incubating\jars\oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== pentaho-ivy: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org.apache.oozie/oozie-main/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]   ==== pentaho-mvn: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/oozie/oozie-main/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-main;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-main.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/oozie/oozie-main/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-main-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== public: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-client;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-client.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== java-net-maven2: tried
[ivy:resolve]     http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-client;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-client.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]   ==== cloudera: tried
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/cdh-build/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.pom
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.oozie#oozie-client;3.1.3-incubating!oozie-client.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/cdh-build/org/apache/oozie/oozie-client/3.1.3-incubating/oozie-client-3.1.3-incubating.jar
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.oozie#oozie-core;3.1.3-incubating: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: org.apache.oozie#oozie-client;3.1.3-incubating: not found
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]
[ivy:resolve]
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
```

can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I searched the cloudera repository and could not find a "3.1.3-incubating" revision for the oozie-core jar:

https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/webapp/search/artifact?1&q=oozie-cor

So, I suggest using a [dynamic revision](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html) in ivy as follows:

```
diff --git a/build.properties b/build.properties
..
..
-dependency.apache-oozie.revision=3.1.3-incubating
+dependency.apache-oozie.revision=[3.1.3,)
..
```

"[3.1.3,)" means any version >= 3.1.3. Running the build, ivy will find:

```
[ivy:resolve]   [4.0.0-cdh5.0.0-SNAPSHOT] org.apache.oozie#oozie-core;[3.1.3,)
```

Hope this helps.